# Using JasperRunManager on JSP: JasperRunManager can not be resolved

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports

I have a problem with *JasperReports 2.0.5*, I want to see a report on web graphic format pdf.

I'm writing these code :

```
<% @ Page errorPage = " error.jsp "% >
<% @ Page import = " net.sf.jasperreports.engine . * "% >
<% @ Page import = " net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util . * "% >
<% @ Page import = " net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export . * "% >
<% @ Page import = " java.util . * "% >
<% @ Page import = " java.io. * "% >
<% @ Page import = " java.sql . * "% >
<% @ Page import = " javax.naming . * "% >
InitContext context = new InitialContext ();
EnvContext context = ( Context) initContext.lookup ( " java :/ comp / env ");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup ( " jdbcLink ");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection ();

  / / PDF View
ReportFile File = new File ( application.getRealPath ( "Reports / WebReport.jasper "));
Map parameters = new HashMap ();
byte [ ] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf ( reportFile.getPath ( ) , parameters, conn ) ;
response.setContentType ( " application / pdf ");
response.setContentLength ( bytes.length ) ;
ServletOutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream ();
ouputStream.write ( bytes , 0, bytes.length ) ;
ouputStream.flush ( ) ;
ouputStream.close ( ) ;
```

And it gives me this error :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException : Unable to compile class for JSP :

An error occurred at line : 32 in the jsp file: / Reports / test.jsp
JasperRunManager can not be resolved
29 : File reportFile = new File ( application.getRealPath ( "Reports /      WebReport.jasper "));
30 : Map parameters = new HashMap ();
31 : out.println ( parameters ) ;
32 : byte [ ] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf ( reportFile.getPath ( ) , parameters , conn ) ;
33 : response.setContentType ( " application / pdf ");
34 : response.setContentLength ( bytes.length ) ;
35 : ServletOutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream ();


Stacktrace :
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError ( DefaultErrorHandler.java : 93)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError ( ErrorDispatcher.java : 330 )
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass ( JDTCompiler.java : 435 )
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile ( Compiler.java : 298)  
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile ( Compiler.java : 277)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile ( Compiler.java : 265)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile ( JspCompilationContext.java : 564 )
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service ( JspServletWrapper.java : 302 )
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile ( JspServlet.java : 329 )
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service ( JspServlet.java : 265)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service ( HttpServlet.java : 803 )
```

In the lib folder I have included these jars:

```
-Groovy-all-1.0.jar
-IText-1.3.1.jar
-JasperReports-2.0.5.jar
-Poi-3.0.1-FINAL-20070705.jar
-Commons-beanutils-1.7.jar
-Commons-collections-2.1.jar
-Commons-logging-1.0.2.jar
```

Sorry for my English

Comment: Are you actually putting all those weird spaces into the `< % @ Page import = " net.sf.jasperreports.engine . * "% >` lines?  Or is that just a problem with pasting into StackOverflow? Also, removed the groovy tag as I can't see how it relates to the question...

Comment: While unfortunately i cant help you with the solution of your problem i just want to let you know that while working for a bigger swiss bank like 7 years ago we decided to first generate the PDFs using JasperReport and then only link the final files rather than having the generated output displayed directly (because none of the developers was able to implement that back in that time so it works with all the Zoom-/ Label-/ Print-/ etc. functionality in any brwoser).

Answer (score 1):

Your imports at the start of the JSP file are not correct. They should have the following format:

```
<%@ page attribute="value" %>
```

(note, page not Page)

and so you should have (duplicates removed):

```
<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" %>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*" %>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.naming.*" %>
```

As they are not in the correct format, the classes within the imported packages (such as JasperRunManager) are not found.